# What is acvpnagent?

Tags: macos, logging, networking, system

I am using MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4) and when I check the /var/log/system.log, I find that a process called **acvpnagent** is constantly active when my computer is in sleep mode.

Here is some pieces of log file:

> Apr 23 02:32:59 localhost acvpnagent[68]: A new network interface has been detected.
>   Apr 23 02:32:59 localhost acvpnagent[68]: Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: FE80:0:0:0:1032:9218:D382:C82 192.168.0.102 FE80:0:0:0:C4A7:49FF:FEC1:C5E5 FE80:0:0:0:5E15:7BA0:ABCE:CC58 FE80:0:0:0:1B1B:F6E8:913D:248A 
>   Apr 23 02:32:59 localhost acvpnagent[68]: Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7972 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical MAC addresses
>   Apr 23 02:32:59 localhost acvpnagent[68]: Function: getInterfacesInternal File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1709 missing PPP destination address for interface "utun0".  Check profile PPPExclusion (set to Automatic?) or contact your administrator.

So what is this process? I tried "$ locate acvpnagent" but I cannot find it. Why does this process attempt to use root privilege?
BTW I was using Shadowsocks then.

Answer (score 7):

It's a Cisco VPN client. If you don't use it, you can follow these instructions to delete it: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/mitcontrib/Cisco+Anyconnect+Manual+uninstall+Mac+OS

In brief, locate the Cisco folder in your Applications and run the Uninstall commands; or or run `sudo /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh`. Otherwise:

```
sudo -s
rm -rf /System/Library/StartupItems/CiscoVPN
rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/CiscoVPN
rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/CiscoVPN.kext
rm -rf /Library/Extensions/CiscoVPN.kext
rm -rf /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-kext.pkg
rm -rf /Library/Receipts/vpnclient-startup.pkg
```

Comment: At the moment location of the script changed:
`sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh`